# How to draw cricket bowler bowl trajectory (Hawkeye) on a cricket pitch using android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, unity-game-engine

I am working on an android project where I need to draw cricket bowl trajectory (Hawkeye) as shown in some of these images.[Sample Hawkeye first Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdHLu.jpg)[Sample Hawkeye second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XaUro.jpg). I am getting set of (x,y,z) coordinates from a JSON file for each ball. The following are the set of JSON (x,y,z) coordinates for one ball.

```
 "bowlerToBatsmanCoordinatesArray": [
                                {
                                    "timestamp": "322",
                                    "x-coordinate": 21.266832577421894,
                                    "y-coordinate": -1.698919658814816,
                                    "z-coordinate": -2.328790240050602
                                },
                                {
                                    "timestamp": "323",
                                    "x-coordinate": 19.744741796911395,
                                    "y-coordinate": -1.7546725841684885,
                                    "z-coordinate": -1.3149661623354854
                                },
                                {
                                    "timestamp": "324",
                                    "x-coordinate": 18.163113002329805,
                                    "y-coordinate": -1.8181315713803832,
                                    "z-coordinate": -0.3726406002332424
                                },
                                {
                                    "timestamp": "325",
                                    "x-coordinate": 16.915619718779418,
                                    "y-coordinate": -1.862530157033399,
                                    "z-coordinate": 0.3835348845275711
                                },
                                {
                                    "timestamp": "326",
                                    "x-coordinate": 15.20037213100631,
                                    "y-coordinate": -1.9429072430715015,
                                    "z-coordinate": 1.3956963104036524
                                },
                                {
                                    "timestamp": "327",
                                    "x-coordinate": 13.85119821269433,
                                    "y-coordinate": -2.014279284076214,
                                    "z-coordinate": 2.084124775615443
                                },
                                {
                                    "timestamp": "328",
                                    "x-coordinate": 12.296925403950393,
                                    "y-coordinate": -2.0848934077227144,
                                    "z-coordinate": 3.002125496768708
                                },
                                {
                                    "timestamp": "329",
                                    "x-coordinate": 10.596762964417975,
                                    "y-coordinate": -2.144978563141154,
                                    "z-coordinate": 3.9854391961105424
                                },
                                {
                                    "timestamp": "330",
                                    "x-coordinate": 9.036151468427795,
                                    "y-coordinate": -2.2139005827019003,
                                    "z-coordinate": 4.809615391795533
                                },
                                {
                                    "timestamp": "331",
                                    "x-coordinate": 7.501265898113952,
                                    "y-coordinate": -2.2343056898435525,
                                    "z-coordinate": 5.5862814469680036
                                },
                                {
                                    "timestamp": "332",
                                    "x-coordinate": 5.832871586047817,
                                    "y-coordinate": -2.288771976826293,
                                    "z-coordinate": 6.52388744451737
                                },
                                {
                                    "timestamp": "333",
                                    "x-coordinate": 4.544282231100583,
                                    "y-coordinate": -2.3516045299032617,
                                    "z-coordinate": 7.093216964758319
                                },
                                {
                                    "timestamp": "334",
                                    "x-coordinate": 3.054858477708966,
                                    "y-coordinate": -2.3089188220338643,
                                    "z-coordinate": 7.747678608542945
                                },
                                {
                                    "timestamp": "335",
                                    "x-coordinate": 1.682549014768629,
                                    "y-coordinate": -2.3181758951823843,
                                    "z-coordinate": 8.328889911339012
                                },
                                {
                                    "timestamp": "336",
                                    "x-coordinate": -0.05046667787178777,
                                    "y-coordinate": -2.390801584323639,
                                    "z-coordinate": 9.271199520767249
                                },
                                {
                                    "timestamp": "337",
                                    "x-coordinate": -1.4353285041036858,
                                    "y-coordinate": -2.421066541823864,
                                    "z-coordinate": 10.060396524431843
                                },
                                {
                                    "timestamp": "338",
                                    "x-coordinate": -3.0121983507937737,
                                    "y-coordinate": -2.4209961295006637,
                                    "z-coordinate": 10.807533772937736
                                },
                                {
                                    "timestamp": "339",
                                    "x-coordinate": -4.59197650125572,
                                    "y-coordinate": -2.4705408392032653,
                                    "z-coordinate": 11.743506277581478
                                },
                                {
                                    "timestamp": "340",
                                    "x-coordinate": -5.977314735189168,
                                    "y-coordinate": -2.43326152798433,
                                    "z-coordinate": 12.344368657862992
                                },
                                {
                                    "timestamp": "341",
                                    "x-coordinate": -6.774567931476065,
                                    "y-coordinate": -2.437360281731236,
                                    "z-coordinate": 12.430819226855204
                                },
                                {
                                    "timestamp": "342",
                                    "x-coordinate": -6.812849075177201,
                                    "y-coordinate": -2.368266061130305,
                                    "z-coordinate": 11.787660059058462
                                },
                                {
                                    "timestamp": "343",
                                    "x-coordinate": -6.819764750787808,
                                    "y-coordinate": -2.3666133637255293,
                                    "z-coordinate": 11.198892295550186
                                },
                                {
                                    "timestamp": "344",
                                    "x-coordinate": -6.6888194243268595,
                                    "y-coordinate": -2.347248721508375,
                                    "z-coordinate": 10.409395437536842
                                },
                                {
                                    "timestamp": "345",
                                    "x-coordinate": -6.226181884542983,
                                    "y-coordinate": -2.323863537326364,
                                    "z-coordinate": 9.158921932188223
                                },
                                {
                                    "timestamp": "346",
                                    "x-coordinate": -6.626138389695026,
                                    "y-coordinate": -2.4013575515908796,
                                    "z-coordinate": 9.098642640540435
                                },
                                {
                                    "timestamp": "347",
                                    "x-coordinate": -7.128428566585037,
                                    "y-coordinate": -2.4376102915814006,
                                    "z-coordinate": 9.139772564217175
                                }
```

Using the JSON I want to plot the Hawkeye as shown in the picture. Can anyone help me to find a solution to this? Any help is highly appreciable. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Look into Bezier curves and OpenGL implementation for Android. It does not matter what library you use to render the trajectory curve, but the concept of Bezier curve would possibly be the most efficient way of going about it.
You would have to know the origin point of the curve (Bowler's release point), the first bounce point of the cricket ball. These coordinates would help you generate the first curve. Then use the latter point as starting point for the second curve and choose some arbitratry point behind the batsman as the end coordinate to generate the second curve. In order for the second curve to align with the first one, the arbitrary second curve end point coordinate must be in line with the initial bounce point of the cricket ball. The y-coordinate of that point should also have the same value or greater than the y-coordinate of the bowler's release point for consistent display aesthetics.

Comment: Hi mindoverflow. I have gone through them but I could not understand how to plot this. Can you please help me with some code?

Comment: I'm afraid it's not so simple. You have to first understand some form of graphics api like OpenGL via some library like let's say GLUT. Then you have to have the actual mathematical understanding of Bezier curves. Here is how you can get started. Research on how to draw curves on Android. This will point you to some API library. Learn to operate that library. Then you research the curve and then draw it on screen. If I give you code, you won't be able to understand it or run it since you might not have fundamental understanding of how graphics is rendered on screen.

Comment: This is a good resource to get you started: https://learnopengl.com/